# confidence interval in quadratic programming

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, p-value, constrained-regression

This is a quadratic programming problem coming from constrained linear regression

$A b + \varepsilon = y$
and
$B^T b >0 $

then minimize  $\varepsilon^T \varepsilon=(A b - y)^T (A b - y)$ which is equivalent to $min(-d^T b + 1/2 b^T D b)$ where $D=2A^TA$, and $2y^TA=d^T$

I would like to get confidence interval in a quadratic programming problem. I am using R. For the curious I provide the below code where I would like to get the confidence interval of the estimated coefficients. I have tried bootstrapping but I am having issues with non-positive definite matrix, I am hoping another approach might be possible. Maybe just shock the estimates and calculate  $min(-d^T b + 1/2 b^T D b)$ which is the cost function for quadratic program.

```
Amat = matrix(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,3,6,9,12,15,1,9,36,81,144,225,1,27,216,729,1728,3375), nrow=6)

Dmat = matrix( c(12,92,992,12152,92,992,12152,158600,992,12152,158600,2150552,12152,158600,2150552,29910872), nrow=4)
dvec = matrix(c(12,96.1128386,1086.2395754,13835.6202146), ncol=1)
Bmat = matrix( c(0,1,3,7,0,1,5,19,0,1,7,37,0,1,9,61,0,1,11,91,0,1,13,127,0,1,15,169,0,1,17,217,0,1,19,271,0,1,21,331,0,1,23,397,0,1,25,469,0,1,27,547,0,1,29,631,0,1,31,721,0,1,33,817,0,1,35,919,0,1,37,1027,0,1,39,1141,0,1,41,1261), nrow=4)
bvec = matrix(c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), nrow=1)


bEst <- solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Bmat, bvec)

bEst$solution
[1]  0.879426809  0.026242400 -0.005319406  0.00035462
```

Comment: You have nominally stated a deterministic quadratic programming problem, which is specified by the inputs Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec.  This problem has a deterministic solution.  Where does the randomness come in? You need to provide a context.

Comment: Thanks, I added further information. Let me know if it is more clear now

Comment: I believe the difficulty here is that for components of $B^\prime b$ that are close to zero, the CI needs to terminate at zero itself.  Related to this--and even thornier--is the problem of determining a CI for the components that have been forced to zero by the restriction. No simple analytical procedure is going to work and developing the asymptotics looks difficult.  Consider a bootstrapped CI or something generic like that, assuming you have a *much* larger dataset.

Comment: this is my dataset. 6 points, yo = c(0.9978865,1.0054508,0.8994358,0.820207,0.9638653,1.3131546), b=c(1,3,6,9,12,15)

Comment: In general one thing you could do is to run Monte Carlo simulation on a sub sample; iff you don't have time series data. In any case you have too few data.

Answer (score -1):

```
yo = c(0.9978865,1.0054508,0.8994358,0.820207,0.9638653,1.3131546)
e <- yo-Amat%*%bEst$solution
R2 <- 1-crossprod(e,e)/crossprod(yo-mean(yo),yo-mean(yo))

degreesOfFreedom <- (nRow - polyOrder - 1)
paramVar <- diag(solve(Dmat*0.5))*crossprod(e, e)/degreesOfFreedom
bEst$paramVar <- paramVar
bEst$tValue <- bEst$solution/sqrt(paramVar)
bEst$pValue <- (1- pt(abs(bEst$tValue), df=degreesOfFreedom ))*2
```

I propose to use a solution similar to linear regression such as $(A^TA)^{-1}\sigma$ where $\sigma$ is error standard deviation. [page 18 of nonlinear regression notes](https://wiki.umn.edu/pub/Wilson/LectureNotes/nonlinear.pdf) has similar formula

Comment: **This answer looks incorrect:** a student $t$ distribution is not the right one to use when any of the constraints holds (or is close to holding).  Could you explain why you think this is correct?